# Live packet capture on linux

Tags: linux, networking, live, capture, packet

I would like to know if there is any possibility to live capture network packets and save it to a variable for example in python.
I need some information to get from it and not to save it to a file.

I need to capture http packets and get source addres and its content, which should be a html code, to extract only text from it and then do the rest of the job on that information.
There is no reason to save every packet to a file because whole process would be more slower. I was looking for quite a long time for any tool to do this but no success.
Please, if you know any tool that could help me to do this, write about it.

Comment: `tcpdump` is probably the tool for you, although I've never personally used it in python.

Comment: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/introduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you have seen [this link](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/) about a library to process PCAP files. Now the question is how to acquire in real time without storing in a file.

Probably easiest is to use a fifo

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/tcpdump.fifo
```

Now you can capture and feed data into the named fifo

```
$ sudo tcpdump -s0 -i eth0 -f /tmp/tcpdump.fifo tcp port 80
```

And in your python program you can open '/tmp/tcpdump.fifo' as the input file as per the instructions in the link.

Alternatively you can try opening '/dev/stdin' in your program and reading the data from there; you could then pipe the PCAP data straight into stdin using the shell and skipping the intermediate named fifo.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -s0 -i eth0 -f - tcp port 80 | ./youprogram.py
```

Comment: @vit0 then you could accept the answer, or at least upvote it!

Comment: sorry, I've tried to upvote but too few reputation :(. Approved as an answer :)